# Ionic - Remove 'Take a Photo' option from file input on iOS

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

The fileInput for Android lets you go straight to selecting an image file from your Photo Gallery while in an iOS device, it lets you choose 'Take a Photo', '...from Library', or 'Browse'. I want to copy the functionality of the Android.

Can this be done?

Comment: You want that if user click on button only image file from your Photo Gallery is open directly ?

Comment: Yes. Just basically remove the "Take a Photo" option

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Any luck with this?  My ionic app crashes on IOS when they choose "take a photo" which isn't even supposed to be an option.